# Changes in Development Server reflects on Live Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a development server and a live server on two different farms pointing to the  same content database.How do i make sure that the changes in the Dev server don't reflect immediately on the live SharePoint server(This SharePoint servers are on two different farms but they point to the same database)

Comment: You mean pointing to the same database server or the database itself?

Comment: Pointing to  the actual content database itself,these database reside in an isolated SQL server

Comment: I am not sure its a good idea to use same content database across multiple farms.

Comment: I know,but i developed and then deployed my master page on the Dev server but it reflected on the live server which i ddnt want and unfortunately this is how my clients server are configured so i need to solve this asap

Comment: I think your best option is to create a separate webapplication and test it out. There is no way you can delay the changes as you are expecting. Also try to unpublish and use draft version for testing. Not sure if that works out.

Comment: Yes true,i think there's no way to delay the changes as they are pointing to the same database.I will create a Test Web App and test everything on it. Il take this dev server offline and use it  as my fallback in case of a disaster.since they are completely identical in this case there wont be any data loss. Thank you for your wonderfull help really much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good practice to Share Content Databases across multiple farms.

For interim you can unpublish the master page and revert it back to the previous version. Take a backup of the content database and restore it as a different web application.

Then use that as the development environment.

Comment: Yes i did revert back to the previous master page, I am not sure i follow aren't they already in different web applications because they are on different servers already(each farm is in its own server)? as each has its own web application on two different servers IIS

Comment: Yes since your existing dev webapplication points to the contentdatabase in live I was asking to setup dev again.

Comment: Ohh now i follow, I will set the new Dev environment then to avoid future headaches Thank you Mr Hashim.